# Add Percent to preloader

Tags: javascript

I have a small preloader that I have used for some time. I want to add a percent to it like 1 2 3 100;

The percent of the page that is loaded.

is there a way to accomplish this using window load?
I have looked a jsfiddle codepens and jquery but have been unable to get an answer. I would like also that if the padge is loaded it don't wait until text is 100% it will fade out the loader.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () { 
    $('.loading-screen').fadeOut(); 
    $('#loadingScreen').delay(400).fadeOut('slow');
    $('body').delay(400).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
});
```

```css
#loadingScreen {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 z-index: 10000;
}

.loading-screen {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -10px 0px 0px -10px;
}

.preloader {
 border: 4px solid #838383;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
 filter: blur(0.7px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
 @keyframes spin {
 0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadingScreen">
  <div class="loading-screen">
    <div class="preloader"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Percent of what though? Not really clear what your expectations are

Comment: the percent of the page loaded

Comment: The page (or resources) is either loaded or not loaded. There is no in between.

Comment: hmm then how are they downing all these percent loaders? if there is no inbetween?